# Asp.Net 5 MVC download image via action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net5

I have a a requirement to control the ability for a client to download images/files based on who they are. We are calling an action with a parameter that allows me to sub in data from session to finish a path, without putting the real path on the client. We then return a FileActionResult from the controller.

It was working. If we found the image, we could create a stream and serve the file, and if we could not, we returned a default image. But, we found that we could easily run into an issue where the stream was open when a new request was made, which resulted in an error. This could then turn into an issue where even the default image could not be downloaded.

I have looked around a lot and we have tested several methods, and these conflicts can still occur. I have started to think that maybe this is not an IO issue, but more of an, "I'm trying to do something wrong" issue.

Is there a way to intercept a call for a static resource, and then adapt the path if it is looking in a specific location, without imposing the rule on all request?

The closest I have found is when creating a View Expander, where I can re-interoperate the path of a called resource, but it is not the same. One is compiled, the other is not.

I don't have any code to show because the approach is uncertain, and unknow. Searches have proven difficult because the terms collide with well know solutions to topics that do not apply.

I am hoping that someone who is more knowledgeable can point me to a method that will treat files in a secure folder as if they are static resources once I have determined they are authorized to access the static resource.

I am using Identity, but I do not extend that identity to system access, nor will I. The only user allowed can be the IISUsr, per my client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried converting the image to byte[] and caching it in-memory?

Comment: When you open the stream to the image, are you ensuring you set the FileShare parameter to ReadWrite - this would allow other streams to read it as well? It would be useful to know what error you were getting.